# What does "Scat." stands for in Latin?

Tags: abbreviations, medicine

I found this prescription in which the word "**Scat.**"  is found. What does this abbreviation stand for?

I've tried googling, and [I found](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=t3fLBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA909&lpg=PA909&dq=scat.%20abbreviation%20latin&source=bl&ots=SeCrl9r7ei&sig=6E7LnpcXVN-hcecy0pkf4WObWOk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjlgbPol6naAhUCh6YKHXOoD4kQ6AEISTAF#v=onepage&q&f=false) that in Latin there is a word "**scatula**" which means **box**. I'm not sure if this word stands for this abbreviation. Normally, many prescription structures don't use this word, but "D.t.d" (detur talis dosis) exactly in the place of "D. Scat.".

[image]

Answer (score 8):

In a word, **yes.**

*D.scat.* means *detur scatula* (“let a box be given”) just like the following *S.* means *signetur* or *scribatur* (“let the following be prescribed”). It is also possible to interpret them as imperatives addressing the chemist: *Da!, Signa!, ...*

Googling yielded [this informative document from a Bulgarian University](http://www.medpharm-sofia.eu/files/DIR%205/Section%209/Structure%20of%20Rp.doc) which clarifies all Latin abbreviations traditionally used in medical prescriptions. In Italy, and I’d bet in many other Western countries, such abbreviations are not used any more. Apparently, this is not the case for other parts of the world.

Comment: Tibi gratulor, quod iam mille puncta tulisti!

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Ego quidem huic collegio pro doctissimis laetissimisque disceptationibus toto corde gratias ago.